# Mirroring UIViews

Tags: ipad, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I am working on an application that supports multiple languages. In order to support languages that start from right to left, I am transforming the view so that views on the right side get shifted to left side as shown in the images below:

[image: View Before Transforming]

[image]

I am using the following code to transform the view

```
 self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
```

What I now want to do is transform the views in its new position in the left to remove the mirrored text. For example, I want to flip the "FLIP LABEL" about its center so that the text is displayed properly. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running the same transform again on the individual subviews - for example:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
}
```

<del>(Or maybe it would be `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)`? I'm not totally sure.)</del>

Comment: `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)` wouldn't do anything, it's the same as `CGAffineTransformIdentity`.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info - I'm not an expert at this CG stuff. Glad this helped!